# How to configure file output in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

My vscode workspace is based on a `A` folder which has a `B` subfolder. There's a following code inside the `B` folder like so:

```
FILE *out = fopen("out.bmp", "wb");
```

When I run this code the `out.bmp` should be created in `B` folder but it is instead created in `A` folder. How can I configure this correctly?

Comment: FILE *out = fopen("/out.bmp", "wb");
to
FILE *out = fopen("Mention B folder path here/out.bmp", "wb");

Answer (score 1):

FILE *out = fopen("/out.bmp", "wb");

---

Replace with given below and make sure the path is clearly define to the B folder

---

FILE *out = fopen("subpath like B folder's path/out.bmp", "wb");

---

### Relative path support for Visual Studio Code

Now you can get the relative path to any file in the workspace.

Just press Ctrl+Shift+H (Mac: Cmd+Shift+H) and select a file. If your workspace has more than 1000 files, you will be prompted to filter that list first. Alternatively, you can press open command palette F1 and search for Relative Path.

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jakob101.RelativePath

Comment: I know this solution but the thing is when I use git, because others don't explicitly write the paths I would often get collisions. I would like vscode to use proper relative path as default.